# Suggestion for RAM upgrade for Dell 5567 i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40 MHz

Tags: laptop, memory

Please can someone recommend how much additional RAM (8GB or 4GB) shall I upgrade to for below present specs:

Model: Inspiron 5000 Series - 5567 Model, 
Processor - i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40 MHz,
Ram - 1x4GB DDR4-2400 MHz with CL 15,
Memory Slots in Laptop = 2

My present RAM usage is always above 80%

Also, please suggest which good RAM can I purchase.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Looking for preferences within India.

Comment: Hi, to help you it would be helpful to know how much you intend to spend on the new memory.

Comment: Looking for a considerably cheaper one .. however from a decent brand. Not too expensive.

Comment: A dollars amount would be a good thing to have :)

Comment: It should be under $110

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dell's memory upgrade tool here are some RAM sticks you can purchase](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/pfydresults/248891?categoryId=4325). According to the [Intel spec sheet](https://ark.intel.com/products/95442/Intel-Core-i3-7100U-Processor-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz) for your processor, you can support up to 32 gb split across 2 slots (16 each). I extracted the memory specs from their sheets to find RAM that will be compatible with your computer. I was only able to find RAM with CAS latency of 15. Since your laptop has two slots, if you keep your current RAM in the first slot, you'll have 12 gb of RAM which should be more than enough for your usage scenarios.

I've recommended RAM that should ship within India for free (I used the zip code of New Delhi)

You have your choice between Kingston and Crucial. They're pretty much the same price and the same from a technical standpoint. You have the luxury of picking the brand you feel more comfortable with.

- [Kingston 8GB 260 pin DDR4-2133 ₹6,999 (MSRP: ₹16,157.15)](https://www.amazon.in/Kingston-Technology-2133MHz-Laptops-KCP421SD8/dp/B0187IKCY0/ref=sr_1_7?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1533223777&sr=1-7&keywords=2133%20DDR4%20260%20pin%208gb&refinements=p_36%3A-755029)
- [Crucial 8GB 260 pin DDR4-2133 ₹7,000](https://www.amazon.in/Crucial-CT8G4SFS8213-2133MHz-260-Pin-Laptop/dp/B01DUULCBM/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1533223777&sr=1-1&keywords=2133%20DDR4%20260%20pin%208gb&refinements=p_36%3A-755029)

Comment: thanks @Bennett-Yeo. However, how what about: https://www.amazon.in/Kingston-Technology-HyperX-Impact-2133MHz/dp/B014R8JPYW/ref=sr_1_6?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1533353390&sr=1-6&keywords=ddr4+sodimm.

Comment: @LokeshwarTailor Yes, this [RAM is compatible](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/HX421S13IB_8.pdf) and one of the sticks that I saw in my query. I did not recommend it because it was over your stated budget. In addition, if you load this RAM in tandem with your current 4gb module, the CAS will drop to 15.